# use UIMenuController with text

Tags: objective-c

So i would like to use the UIMenuController to display text. i would like to add in help buttons (press a little button and something will pop up describing what something does) that would display either a UIMenuController or something that looks similar to it. it would just display a few lines of text and dismiss when pressed.

it kinda looks like UIMenuController is only meant for button selection. i could just use one button and set the title to the message i wish to display, but am doubtful on how well that would work. are there any other options available?

Comment: In other words, you want to add your own content to uimenucontroller?

Comment: Yes i would. i thought i found an objective c program by apple that did this, but i can't seem to find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html) takes it content from its `menuItems` property and the documentation says :

> The default value is nil (no custom menu items). Each menu item is an
>   instance of the UIMenuItem class. You may create your own menu items,
>   each with its own title and action selector, and add them to the
>   editing menu through this property. Custom items appear in the menu
>   after any system menu items.

So you are obliged to use [UIMenuItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html) objects as content for your `UIMenuController`. UIMenuItem only inherits from `NSObject`, and stores only a title and an action, both required. This make you unable to use any other kind of data as `UIMenuItem`.

As it is not an `UIView`, you can give it a `UIButton` or a `UIImageView`.

You could think to override `UIMenuController` but again it is a direct child of `NSObject`, so it doesn't have any behavior for customization.

The only solution left to you, is to rewrite your own `UIMenuController`, deriving it from [UIToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for example. This would give you more or less the same look, you just have to customize the arrow and the round corner.

Comment: thats kinda what i was thinking. i was hoping there was something special about uimenuitem that would allow me to do this. now the question would be is there a library that already exists that can provide what i'm looking for.  thanks for the inpute

Comment: I was in the same problem and did much searches, I didn't found anything. We decided to implement another solution, so we didn't recoded a UIMenuController. No problem, and good luck ;) If you ever find something, post it here